# How to disable mobile/tablet native keyboard on a text field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a text field that is always focused and it is used for searching by a barcode scanner. The problem is that in mobile devices I get the native keyboard at the bottom which I don't want. I want the input to have the default behaviour except only to not have the native keyboard in mobile devices.

I found that the read only property disables the native keyboard but it does not solve the problem as the barcode scanner won't work.

```
   <Input
   id="search-auto-focus"
   autoFocus
   onFocus={(event) => event.target.select()}
   placeholder="Search item"
   value={searchQuery}
   onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
   onKeyPress={(e) => {
     if (e.key === 'Enter') searchInventoryItemBy(searchQuery, () => 
      setSearchQuery(''))}}
   className={classes.textField}
   />
```

Comment: If you are using Input for display purpose only then why bother using native Input, switch to View or Text and render it with border and possibly with background to make it look like an input

Comment: @Rikin I want to be able to type and search, but only in devices with physical keyboard or barcode scanner. The native keyboard on mobile devices should be removed somehow.

Comment: In that case you would probably need to rely on library and detect if mobile, react-native gives you `Platform` using which you can detect OS and then hide show your display or input stuff.

Comment: @Rikin It is a react-js not a react-native project. Does it matter ? You mean to find something similar right ?

Comment: Right either find something similar or write your own little helper, upto you. I just meant to give you an example